# How can i implement this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that has 3 buttons. And I want to locate two textviews to each imageview. How can i implement this layout? AbsoluteLayout is enough for my needs?

Here is my layout part.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >       

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/btn1"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"             
             android:background="@drawable/gray" />


         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/btn2"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"             
             android:background="@drawable/gray" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/btn3"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"             
             android:background="@drawable/gray" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to implement this layout. Boxes are imageview.
[a busy cat http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2385/layoutrq.jpg](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2385/layoutrq.jpg)

Comment: try not to use AbsoluteLayout at all as it has been deprecated since API level 3

Comment: Provide some kind of visual representation of what you want to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linear Layout you can do like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="#F0F0F0" >

       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:text="TextView" />
       </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:text="TextView" />
       </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:text="TextView" />
       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **RelativeLayout** instead of ImageView :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would recommend to create a separate layout and class for it for reusing.

Answer (score 0):

use Button instead of ImageView.

Comment: I want to locate two textviews on imageview or button. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, RelativeLayout may help you.

Comment: But, I must use imageView. So can I use absolutelayout locate two textviews to each imageview?

Comment: So, where exactly do you want to locate these two textviews?

Comment: absoluteLayout is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Button instead of ImageView, You probably want a custom button background? 
Use this:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

Or this to still use the image file:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Comment: Ok but I need to locate two textviews on imagebutton or imageview? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">       

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">   

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 2" />

        </RelativeLayout>    

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
            android:background="@drawable/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">   

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 4" />

        </RelativeLayout>    

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
            android:background="@drawable/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">   

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label 6" />

        </RelativeLayout>    

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: Check now. You can set the background of the relativeLayouts to whatever you wanted in the imageviews and set a clicklistener so they act like buttons.

Comment: This code is adding elements to layout vertically but it must be horizontally.